# AngularJs : How to use ng-repeat for ranges

Tags: angularjs

I want to loop html select option with a number(5).

I have tried below code but not working :

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="n in [] | range:5" value="{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Range limits the current array. But your array doesn't have anything. ng-repeat is working for defined array. So you can define an array in your scope and use it.

html

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="TestController">
  <select>
    <option ng-repeat="n in myNumberArray" value="{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

controller

```
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.myNumberArray = new Array(5);
}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/11760/)